# Refer to a number which comes after every 5 numbers

Tags: sentence

I want to refer to a number which comes after every 5 numbers, (eg. 5, 10, 15, 20 .. ). How can I say it it in a proper sentence?
Thanks.

Comment: _The number coming after every 5 numbers_ sounds like a proper sentence

Answer (score 1):

I **think** you're after a single word like *quinquennial,* which refers to “every fifth year”.

I looked up the phase “every fifth” in OED. There are five definitions which include it, one of which is irrelevant and another which is duplicated.

> *penteteric,* occurring every fifth year (from Greek)
>   *quinquennial,* occurring every fifth year (from Latin)
>   *quintan,* occurring every fifth day

Those are specific. There isn't a word for every fifth item in a general sequence.

Thus for an adverb similar to *quinquennially* you would need an adverbial phrase such as *at* or *after every fifth number*.

Comment: +1. Depending on context you can also say something more mathy like, "mod 5" or "multiples of 5".